# How to use ProtectedBrowserStorage to store and pass data scoped to the tab between seperate BlazorServer applications?

Tags: c#, session, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a list that contains user data for an internal web application. It is populated as they log into the application.

```
public List<UserModel> user;
user = await _db.GetUser(username);
//check password and other things
```

I then store this using  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;`

```
await Storage.SetAsync("userData", user);
```

After performing 2FA and logging into the application the user has the option to navigate to other applications on the internal server. These are separate Blazor Server applications. I then set some addition user stuff and again call  `Storage.SetAsync` and navigate them to the new application with the storage set using the same web browser tab.

```
private async Task GoToBlaBlaApp_Click()
{
    await Storage.SetAsync("userData", user);
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("https://blabla//blabla/blabla");
}
```

When the receiving application is hit I call `Storage.GetAsync` and I'm greeted with a null reference for "userData".

```
public List<UserModel>? users;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        users = (await Storage.GetAsync<List<UserModel>>("userData")).Value ?? null;
    }
}
```

It's my understanding that `ProtectedSessionStorage` is scoped to the browser tab so I can't see why this wouldn't work. What's going wrong?

Comment: You set the protected storage in one Blazor Server application, and you'd like to get it in the another Blazor Server application?

Comment: @AlirezaK Correct. Is it possible? Or is it individual to each application? I thought if the session lives as long as the tab is open it would be able to access the data.

Comment: No, It's not possible. Exactly, it's individual for each app. Each Blazor Server App has the own local/session storage.

Comment: This seems promising:https://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps